# Add nop around entry point of exe

Tags: c, windows, winapi, portable-executable

I try to develop a packer which doesn't rely on adding a further section to the pe file. How can I insert space for the decryptor stub around the entry point in the following two cases:

1. At compile time, means I have a source code and I want to tell the compiler (in my case: gcc -minGW64) to insert some `nop` instructions around maincrtstartup/ entry point ?
2. With a binary, which is probably a lot more difficult. 
   As far as I understand I would need to split the binary into 2 pieces (at the entrypoint), add the `nop`'s between them, merge them again and fix all function addresses and the values in the pe header. Is there a library (Python, C++) which can insert nop's into a binary?

Edit: To further specify the 2nd case:

Assume you have a binary file in pe format and you want to insert some nop opcodes into the .text segment of the file.

Let's say the assembly of the file looks like this:

```
push ebp 
add eax, 5
inc ecx
pop ebp
```

And I want to insert some nop in between add eax, 5 and inc ecx.

Comment: The problem is way too broad to be appropriate for stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need some sort of hotpatching? Question is a bit broad, but you might want to look at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110921-00/?p=9583

I believe it requires use of MS VC

Answer (score 0):

For #1, I don't think this can be done in C compiler. You can use intrinsics. But I'm not sure you can use C intrinsics in global scope to do a wrapper. I guess it is possible to make some static space and do it in runtime as writing nops and copying the function. Still, I think easiest way to achieve this would be compile the function, copy-paste the instructions from disassembly to .asm file and add those nops you want, then compile again with nasm or whatever assembler you decide to use and link the obj.

I don't think there is any public library for #2.

Answer (score 0):

make a c++ executable that starts a process of your "cracked" .exe and pauses it straight after, nops the functions at a certain memory address you find in CheatEngine (I think the hex code for nop is x90, so change op codes you find at the memory addresses found with cheat engine), then resumes the .exe , it then runs with that stuff nopped. And then this is now your cracked launcher.

Or find a way to recompile the c++ .exe with the non cracked exe.